# How to bypass level of detail table calculation limitation

Tags: tableau-api

I want to use LOD to get how many customers are spending over $1k and flag all the activity for each customer after they hit that threshold. I am using a table calculation to get a running total of their cumulative spend: `RUNNING_SUM(SUM(SPEND))`

Ideally I would like to do something like this: `{FIXED year(date), cust_id: IF RUNNING_SUM(SUM(SPEND)) >1000 then 1 end}`
And then add that calculated field as a filter, however Tableau does not support using LOD with table calculations. Are there any good workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Quite interesting topic, but I'm not sure if I got it straight.

With the following solution, you can see just the transactions after 1K for each user.

[image]

Is this what you want?

I'm asking beacuase if you need to count (transactions or users) I think there's no way due to the problem you've already pointed out.

Otherwise, if you "just" need to track the activity starting from the ones triggering the 1k limit, this could be a solution.

Comment: The end goal is to sum a different column after that 1k limit. 

It seems like this solution displays the activity over 1k, and you're saying there's no way to sum a different column?